# Failed: 09:42:58 Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms error in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have done automated testing recording my test case using Selenium IDE. I get the following error while testing out my recording in selenium IDE. How do I resolve the error?

It shows **Failed:
09:42:58
Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms**

[Click here to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7CSc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Im very new to automated testing and have come across this error quite a few times. I have resolved it in two different ways:

1. Insert a wait time of say 50000ms OR
2. Delete the command and set it again

I've found the latter to be more useful as it keeps the test steps down.